# how to wait for a boolean response from a method that performs a SQLite query

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite

I have a service that performs the different queries to my local database SQLite (DATASERVICE.CS), but in this service I want to perform a method that erases all the records of a table and that if it did it successfully, return true, and if he could not do it, return false.

DATASERVICE.CS:

```
 public async Task<bool> DeleteAllUser()
 {
        var queryUser = await this.connection.ExecuteAsync("delete from [UserLocal]");

        if (queryUser == true)
        {
             return true;
        }
        else
        {
             return false;
        }
 }
```

[image: function]

The problem that arises is that this method returns an integer, sometimes it is 1 and sometimes it is 0 (I do not understand why this behavior)

[image: 1]
[image: 0]

How can I make this function return a Boolean? Am I using the `ExecuteAsync` correctly? Should I use `QueryAsync`? any help for me?

Comment: What about `int numAffectedRecords = connection.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();`
It should return the affected records, you can then check if `numAffectedRecords  > 0`. Don't know if that's the best approach.. some correct me if it's not please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You probably use Dapper, because IDbConnection dont have ExecuteAsync() and QueryAsync(). That will be nice to next time tell us.
2. Query() and QueryAsync() is for SELECTs.
3. Number which is returned by Execute is count of affected rows - if had table 2 rows and you call DELETE FROM TABLE, you got number 2.

So then you can write something like this:

```
public async Task<bool> DeleteAllUser()
{
    try
    {
        var queryUser = await this.connection.ExecuteAsync("delete from [UserLocal]");
        return true;
    }
    catch(Excpection e)
    {
        // log e
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        connection?.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL `Delete` returns numbers of rows affected. So if it returns 0, you removed 0 users. In both cases operation is successful. If something would go wrong it would throw an exception. So it depends what do you count as success or failure. If you want to return `false`, if neither users were removed you can do this:

```
 public async Task<bool> DeleteAllUser()
 {
        var amountOfAffectedRows = await this.connection.ExecuteAsync("delete from [UserLocal]");

        if (amountOfAffectedRows > 0)
        {
             return true;
        }

        return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As taken from [the documentation straight in code](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLiteAsync.cs#L901) it says

```
/// <returns> 
/// The number of rows added to the table.
/// </returns>
```

So, this means, in your example that 0 or 1 row is removed. To turn that into a boolean, the best thing you can probably do is wrap it in a method and let that return a boolean. Or, simply catch the result in a variable and check if it is more than 0.

Comment: It currently says "`The number of rows modified in the database as a result of this execution.`".